# Proximity Detection iOS using corebluetooth any other alternative

Tags: ios, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

i used sample app from apple which is BLTE tranfer.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/BTLE_Transfer/Introduction/Intro.html

using the sample i was able to make a bluetooth trans - receiver. Everything works great in the foreground. But only concerns is the background.

Scanning- 
Scanning cannot be done for all the devices in the background. we need specific UUID for scanning. But how long will the app be running in the background even if we know the UUID for which we are scanning??

Transmission -
iOS doesnot transmit UUID while in the background. So how do i scan for such devices??

Is there a solution to my problem.i just need to scan the environment with possible all bluetooth devices and receive their RRSI signal strength **in the background**. and i dont need to connect to the devices.

Comment: When scanning in the background you must specify the service, not device UUID that you are looking for. Similarly, an iOS App can advertise a specific service as a peripheral in the background. You cannot scan all services while in the background

Comment: thank you so much for the comment. but even if we do that how long will the app be running in the background to detect all the devices with same service.??

Comment: Until iOS terminates it due to memory pressure or until the user terminates it by swiping up